# Add JavaScript to Google Sites

Tags: javascript, google-sites

My goal is to create a nice radar chart, which I'd like to display on my Google site. I found the rcharts website quite helpful. My question is now, how do I implement the simple java script code on my Google Site? An example of what I'm after is a demo in the RGrqaph download:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable

And it's called: demos/radar-basic.html

Thank you very much!

I tried the link proposed below as well, however, I get the following error when I post everything into the HTML box: 2+13 - 30: failed to load external url RGraph.radar.js

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJUK.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/caja